# An upper bound of the probability involving Bernoulli on the power

Tags: probability, random-variables, concentration-of-measure, bernoulli-distribution

I would like to find an upper bound of

$\text{Pr}\{a^{u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4}+a^{l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4}\leq a^{u_1+u_2+l_1+l_2}+a^{u_3+u_4+l_3+l_4}\}$,

where $a>1$ and $l_1,\cdots,l_4$ follows i.i.d Bernoulli$(p)$, $u_1,\cdots,u_4$ follows i.i.d. Bernoulli$(p(1+\delta))$ with $\delta>0$.

I tried Chernoff bound, but it looks very messy. Are there any specific concentration bounds that can be applied to this type of problem?

Comment: You can rewrite it as $\Pr((a^{u_1 + u_2} - a^{l_3 + l_4})(a^{u_3 + u_4} - a^{l_1 + l_2}) \leq 0)$. Let $q = \Pr(a^{u_1 + u_2} \leq a^{l_3 + l_4})$. Then required bound is $2q(1-q)$. You can find that $q = (1-p)^2 + 2p(1-p)(1 - p(1+\delta))^2 + p^4(1+\delta)^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution, I'm considering a [slightly generalized version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593626/an-upper-bound-of-the-probability-involving-bernoulli-on-the-power-generalized) . Any thoughts will be appreciated.